# Need To Add New Keys and Values Into Plist Using Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, json, nsstring

I have created `JSON` data store Into `Plist`. Now the problem is after JSON data storage, I need to add two set of keys into every array of `dictionary` items like below Image_2.The key name `isParent - Boolean YES` and `isChild - Boolean YES` with `levels` like mentioned below Image_2.

Now I have below structure of plsit datas Its perfectly working by below code.

[image]

I need to add two keys for outside of object subjectcount and inside of objectsubjectcount red marked datas.

[image]

```
NSDictionary *JSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves | NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
 NSDictionary *response = JSON[@"response"];
 NSArray *keys = [response allKeys];

 NSMutableArray *objects = [NSMutableArray new];
 for (NSString *key in keys) {
     NSMutableDictionary *object = response[key];
     NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"subject = %@",object[@"subject"]];
     NSArray *objectsWithSameSubject = [objects filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
     NSInteger subjects = [object[@"subject"] integerValue];
     if (subjects > 0) {

         NSMutableArray *Objects_Subjectcount = [NSMutableArray new];
         [object setObject:Objects_Subjectcount forKey:@"Objects_Subjectcount"];
         for (NSInteger i = 0; i < subjects; i++) {
             [Objects_Subjectcount addObject:object];// object or anything you need

         }
     }
     [objects addObject:object];
 }

 NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
 NSString *documentsPath = paths.firstObject;
 NSString *plistPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"File.plist"];
 NSError *writeError = nil;
 NSDictionary *finalDict = @{@"Objects": objects};
 NSData *plistData = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataWithPropertyList:finalDict format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0 options:NSPropertyListImmutable error:&writeError];
 if(plistData){
     [plistData writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];
 }
 else {
     NSLog(@"Error in saveData: %@", error);
 }
```

`NOTE :` all the datas store by JSON but after storage need to add additional values by manually! Thats I am trying

Comment: Thank you @Itteh Kitteh! Do you know how to make above process?

Comment: inside the inner frolic do [Objects_Subjectcount addObject:@{@"level":@(0), @"isChild": @(YES)}];
And in outer loop [object setObject:@(yes) forKey:@"isParent"];

Comment: Try something before asking, you just copied the code from previous answer and asking help...

Comment: Please go through the following links http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 0):

The object from response[key] is immutable so it can't be modified as below:

```
[object setObject:Objects_Subjectcount forKey:@"Objects_Subjectcount"];
```

Making it mutable as below, it can be modified by any method add/remove/set.

```
NSMutableDictionary *object = [response[key] mutableCopy];
```

Hope using below modified block, you would see required changes.

```
NSDictionary *JSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves | NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
NSDictionary *response = JSON[@"response"];
NSArray *keys = [response allKeys];

NSMutableArray *objects = [NSMutableArray new];
for (NSString *key in keys) {
    NSMutableDictionary *object = [response[key] mutableCopy];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"subject = %@",object[@"subject"]];
    NSArray *objectsWithSameSubject = [objects filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
    NSInteger subjects = [object[@"subject"] integerValue];
    if (subjects > 0) {

        [object setObject:@"" forKey:@"level"];
        [object setObject:@(YES) forKey:@"isParent"];

        NSMutableArray *Objects_Subjectcount = [NSMutableArray new];
        for (NSInteger i = 0; i < subjects; i++) {
            [Objects_Subjectcount addObject:@{@"level":@(0), @"isChild":@(YES)}];
        }
        [object setObject:Objects_Subjectcount forKey:@"Objects_Subjectcount"];

    }
    [objects addObject:object];
}

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsPath = paths.firstObject;
NSString *plistPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"File.plist"];
NSError *writeError = nil;
NSDictionary *finalDict = @{@"Objects": objects};
NSData *plistData = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataWithPropertyList:finalDict format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0 options:NSPropertyListImmutable error:&writeError];
if(plistData){
    [plistData writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];
}
else {
    NSLog(@"Error in saveData: %@", error);
}
```

Comment: I need to add two manual values after Json data load above mentioned red mark values i need to add after json data stoarage.@bunty

Comment: Could you please help me? I need to add two keys after loaded JSON data!

Comment: I just changed my answer, hope you will get desired results.

Comment: @bunty sorry for distubing you If u modified within my code I can easily understand!

Comment: I copied whole your code including my changes.

Comment: @bunty Its not working! I have checeked my plist there nothing new values added

Comment: Can you share original plist, I will look into it?

Comment: @bunty please help me dude!

Comment: @Helpme, please check now. As you have not given plist, I have created on my own named "file_name.plist". Rename it with yours and try.

Comment: @bunty Its not working! Please check and give me once again!If I use your code nothing data into plist!

Comment: @Apple_Ajay, can you provide sample project in which there is that code and plist?

Comment: @bunty I Can you read my question again!

Comment: Updated answer again. I got file as output that looks same on this link: http://www.image-share.com/upload/3131/110.jpg

Comment: @bunty thank you so much BTW isChild values actually Dictionary of Array Its automattically created by JSON into plist If I create         NSMutableArray *Objects_Subjectcount = [NSMutableArray new]; then Its replacing JSON responses.

Comment: for (NSInteger i = 0; i < subjects; i++) {
            [Objects_Subjectcount addObject:@{@"level":@(0), @"isChild":@(YES)}];
        }
        [object setObject:Objects_Subjectcount forKey:@"Objects_Subjectcount"]; If I am using I can add ischild keys and values but I am losting my JSOn data. Need to add with JSOn data@bunty

Answer (score 0):

```
NSData *plistData = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataWithPropertyList:finalDict format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0 options:NSPropertyListMutable error:&writeError];
```

Retrieve data from plist like this.

```
NSMutableDictionary *plistDic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
```

Now suppose  you want to update first array of dictionary then

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init:[plistDic objectAtIndex:0]]
```

You can do for loop if you want to change all array data...Right i am just using first object data..

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init:[array objectAtIncex:0]];
[dict addObject:"yourdata" forKey:"yourkey"];
[array replaceObject:dict atIndex:0];
[plistDic replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:array];
```

And last

```
[plistDic writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];
```

Comment: Could you please update my code above. I need to add two keys on under Items and another one boolean key need to add subjectcount Items for all Items need to add. Check above posted Image!

Comment: Can u update up answer!