# Add Additional Keys and Values Within PropertyList Using iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, plist

I need to add below mentioned `keys` and `values` (Image Red Marked Values) Into `propertylist`.

Needed Structure (need to add Red marked keys and values at same position)

[image: description here]

Now my plist:

[image: description here]

My Exact Scenario Below

1. I have created plist and Into the plist I am getting the storage
   data from `JSON` parser.
2. I have one standard mediatory storage structure based on that Its
   storing (I have added above Image two)
3. Now I need to add two boolean keys and values by
   manual, Into the plist. Where and which position all the information
   I have marked and mentioned by above Image one.
4. `JSON` parse to store data Into plist for that I have used below code

Below code I am using:

```
NSDictionary *JSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves | NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
 NSDictionary *response = JSON[@"response"];
 NSArray *keys = [response allKeys];

 NSMutableArray *objects = [NSMutableArray new];
 for (NSString *key in keys) {
     NSMutableDictionary *object = response[key];
     NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"subject = %@",object[@"subject"]];
     NSArray *objectsWithSameSubject = [objects filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
     NSInteger subjects = [object[@"subject"] integerValue];
     if (subjects > 0) {

         NSMutableArray *Objects_Subjectcount = [NSMutableArray new];
         [object setObject:Objects_Subjectcount forKey:@"Objects_Subjectcount"];
         for (NSInteger i = 0; i < subjects; i++) {
             [Objects_Subjectcount addObject:object];// object or anything you need

         }
     }
     [objects addObject:object];
 }

 NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
 NSString *documentsPath = paths.firstObject;
 NSString *plistPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"File.plist"];
 NSError *writeError = nil;
 NSDictionary *finalDict = @{@"Objects": objects};
 NSData *plistData = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataWithPropertyList:finalDict format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0 options:NSPropertyListImmutable error:&writeError];
 if(plistData){
     [plistData writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];
 }
 else {
     NSLog(@"Error in saveData: %@", error);
 }
```

Comment: There is no such a big deal with adding a new key. Simply write the dictionary to plist, all keys will be there.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya how to do that ?

Comment: @Anitha  whats the issue with that code?

Comment: @PiyushPatel I need to add additional keys like first Image! all the datas I am getting from JSON and storing into plist by using above code everything fine but Now I need to add manually two boolean keys and levels with values into that Items like posted Image 1.

Comment: @Anitha: Are you able to form Dictionary from JSON?

Comment: Yes buddy above same code and same structure is my process. @AnoopVaidya

Comment: So you are not able to write the dictionary in plist?

Comment: Yes I cant able to write. The exact needed I  want to add that isChild and isParent boolean and level values at same postion by hard code. Other datas storing from JSON! @AnoopVaidya

Comment: Why at same position. its a dictionary, if it is in proper key (parent keys till root) you can fetch it out....

Comment: No need same position but within first array need to add isParents and level then within objectsubjectcount items need to add isChild and level values because Its both I am using for accordion tableview. If Its add then Only It will work!Check Image one within Red mark and update my code please@AnoopVaidya

Comment: I cant update, but give a sample code, that would help you to understand... wait for few minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Assume your existing plist is created by this code:

```
NSDictionary *dic = @{@"Planet":@"Earth",
                      @"Earth":@{@"1":@"Asia",
                                 @"2":@"Africa"}
                      };

[dic writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

[image]

Then you need to insert a new key-value pair inside Earth.

```
//read
NSDictionary *readDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];
//create a mutable dict to edit it
NSMutableDictionary *mDict = [readDict mutableCopy];
//read the key-value for earth, and we are gonna edit it
NSMutableDictionary *earthDict = mDict[@"Earth"];
//set new object, it can be anything, string, array, dictionary etc
[earthDict setObject:@{@"myName":@"Anoop"}
          forKey:@"new"];
//write it back to same file
[mDict writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

Now the plist looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Anitha: if this helps you out, or any query feel free to reach me.

Comment: Buddy but mine Array Of Dictionary @Anoop Vaidya

Comment: @Anitha: Read the comments, in code snippet. in the object you can put anything... and to edit any existing key-value, use as I showed.

Comment: @Anitha: What didn't work? Use my code, and try to add one array or string first. Then replace the string with dictionary.

Comment: I have posted above buddy!

Comment: @Anitha: from where I would get values in `data`?

Comment: This is my question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34488990/how-to-store-json-parsed-data-into-plist-using-objective-c

Comment: @Anitha: I cant understand, whether you are just a beginner in Obj-C or simply irritating me.... I asked `data` in this `NSDictionary *JSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data`. From here only you get the dictionary and create plist file.

Comment: That Data if u go that link u can understand everything. @Anoop

Comment: How everyone is using the same code!!! Are you all guys attending some ios training programme and doing sample projects?